# How to replace column values in one dataframe from other dataframe on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar","Panda", "Panda", "Zootopia", "Zootopia"],"B":[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar","Panda", "Panda", "Zootopia", "Zootopia","Toy Story"]})
```

If column **A** in df and df1 matches then replace df1 column A by df column **B** value also count number of values not replaced and take a list of them.

Expected Output

```
    A
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   0.0
5   1.0
6   1.0
7   1.0
8   Toy Story
```

Not Replaced Count: 1

Not Replaced DataFrame:

```
 0  A
     Toy Story
```

Comment: i need in pandas

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
num = len(df['A'])
if all(df1['A'][:num]==df['A'][:num]):
    df1['A'][:num] = df['B']
```

Output for df1:

```
           A
0          0
1          1
2          1
3          1
4          0
5          1
6          1
7          1
8  Toy Story
```

---

If you did not want to alter df1, you could make a copy of it and run the code:

```
num = len(df['A'])
df1_copy = df1.copy()
if all(df1_copy['A'][:num]==df['A'][:num]):
    df1_copy['A'][:num] = df['B']
```

Output for df1:

```
           A
0        foo
1        foo
2        foo
3        bar
4      Panda
5      Panda
6   Zootopia
7   Zootopia
8  Toy Story
```

Output for df1_copy:

```
           A
0          0
1          1
2          1
3          1
4          0
5          1
6          1
7          1
8  Toy Story
```

Comment: Can u help me with getting a dataframe of not replaced one directly

Comment: You could add something like `df1_copy = df1.copy()`. I will edit my answer

Comment: I doesn't want that I need to need a seperate dataframe that has not replaced columns of df1

Comment: Yes, the last code does that. `df1` is left untouched, and `df1_copy` is altered. Try out that last code.

Comment: I only want this as output 0  A
     Toy Story